# wildignore does not ignore files if they exist within a symlink

Tags: wildmenu

I have found that wildignore does not ignore files if they exist within a symlink to a folder. As an example in case I dont make sense:

```
mkdir testfolder
touch testfolder/testfile
# In nvim:
set wildignore=**/testfolder/**
:find te<Tab> # Nothing is returned here (as expected)
# In terminal:
ln -s testfolder symlinkfolder
# In nvim
set wildignore=**/testfolder/**
:find te<Tab> # Completion is completed even though filepath is ./testfolder/testfile
```

Is there some method to have the wildignore run on the full filepath?

Thanks

Comment: The directory is a symlink so the path is not `./testfolder/testfile` but `./symlinkfolder/testfile` and the pattern in `wildignore` doesn't match. I don't think there is a way to tell Vim to generally ignore symlinks but I might e wrong.